# Backup on . android_secure - Missing Apps on MicroSD

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, backup, external-sd

I Have been Backup and Formatted my MicroSD. After then I Copy again my backup files, But  - Apps on MicroSD is  Disappear, I check on Application Manager its Still There but not show in menu drawer.

As I read related Question on [Upgrade SD Card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19409/apps-missing-after-upgrading-sd-card), I Tried to copy all files with command prompt/by windows. But I confuse how I backup on .android_secure that have all asec apps on micro sd. I copy via card reader/usb. its fine, when media scanning running, i check on that folder again an all asec is missing. anybody knew the alternative method on this problems.?

I Use Galaxy Ace on Gingerbread (2.3.3) with Class 10 8GB MicroSD.

Thanks lot. :D

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? If you didn't backup .android_secure there's not much we can do to help you with that. Windows should copy folder beginning with `.` just fine, unlike some Linux tools.  Use Explorer if the command line is finicky.

Comment: @Matthew He has copied `.android_secure`, but its not reflected back in device. Once I also faced the same problem with my Galaxy S.

Comment: @SachinShekhar is right.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MicroSD is generally hot swappable (unlike SIM card), but this thing screws things up.

First, turn off the device. Remove old MicroSD. Clone it including `.android_secure`. Insert new MicroSD while device is off. Then, boot the device.

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply.. Thanks.. I Tried that, and Its Works.. Many Thanks.. :D