# How To Switch To A Higher Storage SDHC Card With Less Hassle And Problems?

Tags: google-play-store, external-sd, force-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upgrade / swap SD card without losing data and installed apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15049/how-to-upgrade-swap-sd-card-without-losing-data-and-installed-apps)

I am about to switch to SanDisk 16GB SDHC from 8GB storage flash card of same brand, but currently have following problems:

1. **Sometimes Android OS forcecloses and restart fixes problem for a while:**

   *This happens again and again by touching back button until switched from application or a home button.*
2. **Android Market v2.3.4 does not update apps:**

   *Apps that are set to update automatically are stuck at "Downloading" as progress meter does not move and i have to update manually by cancelling download which negates the point in automatic app update. Gets stuck at download progress bar but progress bar is animated. After cancelling automatic download, i can re-download again manually.*

Should aforementioned problems be taken care of before switching to a higher storage card or after? Additionally how would you go about rectifying aforementioned problems?

I want to upgrade manually to Police Market from my old 2.3.4 but i cannot see .APK file of old market and cannot backup it. Maybe i should just backup old SDHC card with Android Market 2.3.4 and keep this one just in case but copy this one as well to newer SDHC card, update old Market from there to Police Market and in case something goes bad, i have backup of old SDHC card?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple questions in one, so let's see how to address them:

1. if those issues you report already happen with the "old" card inserted, they probably won't get worse with the "new" card (if they are card-related at all) -- so I would not connect these two. Though I had that #1 problem with a certain card (but not with another), after a ROM switch (replaced stock by Cyanogen) the problem switched as well (lucky me, now the new and bigger card had no problems anymore) -- so there might be certain compatibility issues, and switching cards *could* even get you rid of that FC problem. But mostly, such FC problems are rather solved by cleaning the cache of affected apps, or (worst case) doing a factory reset. If your device is rooted, wiping the Dalvik Cache (an option available with enhanced Recovery) would be an alternate approach to the factory reset, in case the Dalvik Cache got messed up.
2. the market issue should not be related to your SD card either. Here it may help to clear the market cache (via *apps->manage apps*).
3. concerning your `.apk`, the solution could be provided by apps like [AppMonster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.android_telefonie.appmanager) -- which creates a copy of `.apk` files from installed apps to your SD card (the Pro version even does so automatically on each install/update, so you can easily switch back to any previous version of an app when the latest version shows problems).
4. keeping the old card for a while (leaving it untouched) never can hurt, as it provides another backup :)

Comment: The main problem I referred to is specifically discussed here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1446961