# How do I migrate from one SD card to another one?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, external-sd, data-transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I switch my Android device's SD card without causing problems?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17402/how-do-i-switch-my-android-devices-sd-card-without-causing-problems)

I just moved to Android from iOS. My new droid is Sony Ericsson Xperia Neo V which came with a 2GB SD card. This card is almost full so I want to get a bigger and faster SD card. I have installed many apps on this SD card so I'm wondering how I can move all the content of the old card to the new one when I finally purchase it. How do I do this?

Comment: Potential duplicates: [How to upgrade / swap SD card without losing data and installed apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15049/how-to-upgrade-swap-sd-card-without-losing-data-and-installed-apps), [How do I switch my Android device's SD card without causing problems?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17402/how-do-i-switch-my-android-devices-sd-card-without-causing-problems), [How To Switch To A Higher Storage SDHC Card With Less Hassle And Problems?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20450/981)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the solution described by *yrajabi* basically works, it might miss some data -- e.g. if you have moved some apps to SD card using *App2SD*, you might miss them afterwards. So a much safer approach is:

1. shut down your device
2. take out the SDCard
3. put the SDCard into a card reader, and attach this card reader to your PC
4. make sure all files are visible in your "copy GUI" (which ever you use)
5. copy all files and directories, including hidden ones, into an empty folder on your computer
6. safely unmount the card, and replace it by the new one
7. same way, copy all data (including hidden files/directories) to the new card
8. safely unmount that card, and place it back into your device
9. power up the device, you are done

This way you can make sure no files/directories have been hidden from you.

Comment: Thanks so much as I forgot about app2sd which I use a lot

Comment: Always glad to help :)

Comment: Does this tactic still work in 2015? Since it looks like my .android_secure map does not included any more items. They seem to be invisible from the file explorer, but I guess they are still there. Will they be copied or not?

Comment: @PeterRaeves Definitely. Nothing has changed in this regard. You cannot see anything in that directory, though, when the card is mounted in your device (except with root powers). To check, use the card reader again.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple, just connect your phone via USB to your PC and copy all folders from your old SD card to a temporary folder on your PC. Then disconnect and eject your old card and insert your new SD card into phone and again connect phone to PC and Copy-Paste all contents back from the temporary folder to your new SD card, and disconnect phone when finished.

P.S: if you refer to potential duplicates below your answer, there is more perfect and better answers!!!

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I thought as much but wanted to be sure first :)

Comment: Be careful with that if you used *App2SD*, in which case it only works partially!

Comment: I have indeed used app2sd to move a couple of apps to my card. So what do I do so I don't loss those apps