# Transferring Apps from sd card to another sd card(HTC Desire HD)

Tags: applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upgrade / swap SD card without losing data and installed apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15049/how-to-upgrade-swap-sd-card-without-losing-data-and-installed-apps)

I have a 2gb sd card and it's full I can't put more music,photos and videos.I will buy an 8gig sd card.I wonder if it will work if I copy all of my apps from the 2 gig to 8 gig I hope it will work

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15049/how-to-upgrade-swap-sd-card-without-losing-data-and-installed-apps

Answer (score 2):

It will not work in case you move all your data to PC and then copy it to the new sd-card(it true for Windows,Linux, Mac as ownership of all applications will be changed)
If you have additional slot for sd-cards on your device then copying data to the new card and then replace the old one with this one. It should work with all rooted devices)

Try copying your apps using some special utilities which copy data saving permissions and ownership. I hope dd on linux will work